# "Apple Mach-O (id) linker" error when adding external libraries to project

Tags: sqlite, linker-errors, fmdb

I added FMDB to my project then added the frameworks libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib, but I still get the build error. If I remove the FMDB classes from my project then it builds just fine. What other things should I check?

Detailed info on the error:

> Ld /Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Products/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.app/iNROMockUp5 normal i386
>      cd /iOSDev/Testing/iNROMockUp5
>      setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>      setenv PATH >"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bi>n:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>      /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 >-isysroot >/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk ->L/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator ->F/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist >/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Intermediates/iNROMockUp5.build/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.build/Objects-normal/i386/iNROMockUp5.LinkFileList -mmacosx->version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lsqlite3 -lsqlite3.0 -framework >MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o >/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Products/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.app/iNROMockUp5
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Intermediates/iNROMockUp5.build/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.build/Objects-normal/i386/fmdb.o and >/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Intermediates/iNROMockUp5.build/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed >with exit code 1
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Intermediates/iNROMockUp5.build/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.build/Objects-normal/i386/fmdb.o and >/Users/gmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNROMockUp5->gjmgpakyszrgwbbxnkdxehexacxm/Build/Intermediates/iNROMockUp5.build/Debug->iphonesimulator/iNROMockUp5.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o for architecture i386
>
> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: The error says you have two main's.

Comment: One of the classes I imported had a "main" of its own and produced the double symbol error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove fmdb.m from your project and you will be fine.

Comment: fmdb.m no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Remove `main.m` from your project and you will be fine.