# Sqlite fmdb lib duplicates symbol for armv7

Tags: sqlite, ios6, fmdb, armv7

I get this error when trying to build on Xcode 4.5 based on iOS 6 SDK

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/nsm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Newsapp-btwcniahgzgkgrbtyloduniznsay/Build/Intermediates/Newsapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Newsapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
    /Users/nsm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Newsapp-btwcniahgzgkgrbtyloduniznsay/Build/Intermediates/Newsapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Newsapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/fmdb.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What is the problem?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876453/apple-match-o-id-linker-error-when-adding-external-libraries-to-project remove fmdb.m from the project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must remove the file `fmdb.m` which got imported along with the FMDB classes.